# Least Squares Regression with Length and Density of input data

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear-algebra

I have a collection of data that I expect to be linear but has a unknown amount of noise to the data. Initially I wanted to use the least squares regression line to determine if the slope, y axis, and variance of the data was acceptable. But, a data set with less data points or data points highly localized to two locations would give similar results. Is there a linear approximation algorithm that takes into account the beginning and end of the data as well as the density of the data? Maybe something that results in a point and a Vector instead of a continuous linear equation?

Some Graphs that have the same linear equation from the LSRL algorithm that I'd like to be able to differentiate.

"Good Well Spaced Data"
[image: Line of spaced points]

"Tightly Packed Data"
[image: Tightly Packed Data Points]

"Short Length"
[image: Short Line]